How to iframe a Google Script web app taking into account the x-frame-options?
I am trying to iframe a web app (with access to anyone) from google script to the client's domain, and receiving:

Refused to display 'https://script.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

I have studied other cases like 1, but I cannot resolve it. Is there any legit way to iframe the web app?

This question is similar to: How to show google.com in an iframe?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your only option is to persuade Google to change it’s server settings to allow you to do this.
